# Concatenate Array of Ranges into a Single Array

Tags: arrays, excel, vba, excel-2016

I have a VBA script aiming to combine the data out of a set of worksheets into one, (without duplicating the columns headers).

For every sheet: The data is a fixed 11 columns wide with identical column headers, and of variable rows in height.

My code so far, including comments and pseudo code where I ran into brain difficulties, modify as needed:

```vb
Sub joinAllOutputs()
    Dim i As Variant
    Dim counter As Variant
    Dim outputSheetsNamesArr()
    Dim outputSheetsArr()
    Dim outputRangesArr()
    Dim rangesArr()
    Dim finalArr()
    Dim finalSheet As Worksheet

    ' The sheet we're putting everything into:
    Set finalSheet = Sheets("TO COPY")

    ' The sheets we're scooping the guts out of:
    outputSheetsNamesArr() = Array("Output - Sales (Net)", "Output - Hours", "Output - Footfall", "Output - Transactions", "Output - Conversion", "Output - ATV", "Output - HS Orders", "Output - HS Sales")
    
    ReDim outputSheetsArr(UBound(outputSheetsNamesArr))
    ReDim outputRangesArr(UBound(outputSheetsNamesArr))
    counter = 0
    For Each i In outputSheetsNamesArr ' iterate through sheet naes
        Set outputSheetsArr(counter) = Sheets(i)
        With Sheets(i) ' enter sheet context
            Set outputRangesArr(counter) = .Range(.Range("A2").End(xlDown), .Range("K2")) 'grab the range of data from the sheet without headers. Sometimes col K is empty so can't trust .End to work.
        End With
        counter = counter + 1
    Next
    
    ' do something here to glue all the ranges into one big range/array (vertically, so it stays 11 columns wide) but also don't forget to include the header row
    
    ' Dim totalNumRows As Long
    ' totalNumRows = 0
    ' totalNumRows = sum up all the range heights
    ' For Each i In rangesArr
    '     totalNumRows = totalNumRows + UBound(i, 1)  ' not sure if 1 or 2 as second argument to UBound will be the rows
    '     finalArr() = Do magic here
    ' Next
    
    ' Dump it into the finalSheet
    ' finalSheet.Range("A1:K2) = get the headers from somewhere - or they just get included into the finalArr somewhere above, whatever works more cleanly!
    
    ' With finalSheet
    '     .Range("A1").Resize(totalNumRows, 11).Value = finalArr
    ' End With


End Sub
```

Please excuse the slightly odd naming, the "output" sheets are named that way as they are the output of a much lengthier process that came before.

Edit: Realising I should clarify I can't use tables and the related Get & Transform (PowerQuery) tools due to the way the data is generated prior. Also stuck on Excel 2016.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Some changes i made, pls try this

```
Sub joinAllOutputs()
outputsheetsnamesarr = Array("Output - Sales (Net)", "Output - Hours", "Output - Footfall", "Output - Transactions", "Output - Conversion", "Output - ATV", "Output - HS Orders", "Output - HS Sales")
Set finalsheet = Sheets("TO COPY")
Worksheets(outputsheetsnamesarr(0)).Range("A1:K1").Copy finalsheet.Range("A1")
firstfree = 2
For Each shname In outputsheetsnamesarr
    Set sh = Worksheets(shname)
    With sh
        sh.Range(.Range("A2").End(xlDown), .Range("K2")).Copy finalsheet.Range("A" & firstfree)
    End With
    firstfree = finalsheet.Range("A1").End(xlDown).Row + 1
Next shname

End Sub
```

Comment: I'm getting an error (`Run-time error '1004' Application-defined or object defined error`) with the copy line that puts the header in. I've resolved it by by hardcoding the ranges: `Sheets(outputSheetsNamesArr(0)).Range("A1:K2").Copy finalSheet.Range("A1:K2")`. Although I'd prefer not to do that it will work for now :) Thank you